# How to change permission of users in RDS?

Tags: mysql, permissions, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

We have created a **MySQL RDS** instance on [AWS](http://aws.amazon.com/) called "lolbob" and while dumping our data over port *3306* using the user that was created during instance creation (also called "lolbob") it fails because we have some stored procedures that require the `SUPER` permission in MySQL.

After googling around for a bit we concluded that the recommended solution to this known problem(TM) is to

1. Add the `log_bin_trust_function_creators` parameter to the *DB Parameter Group* used for the instance and apply/reboot instance.
2. Log in to the instance itself using *SSH* and use the mysql client program from commandline with rdsadmin user to grant the `SUPER` permissions to the default instance db user.

There is a special rdsadmin user with all permissions that is only accessible from localhost for security reasons, otherwise we could just use that.

Now I am usually a fan of the command line but this is supposed to be *PaaS* cloud in 2015 right? So the question is (you might have guessed it already) how can we just have the default user for our new instances have the `SUPER` permission in MySQL by default? And if that is not possible, what is the next best thing? For example would it be possible to somehow change the settings of that user from *AWS* console? Anything but having to log in using *SSH* and use mysql  client program from command line!